# Nougat - Disable settings on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, bluetooth, 7.0-nougat

I currently have my phone set up to automatically unlock when it's connected to my car's Bluetooth, which is super convenient. However, my car's Bluetooth stays active while my car is off, and my phone is capable of connecting to it from almost anywhere in my office building.

So, when I leave my car, I turn off Bluetooth on my phone since I want my phone to lock. But right now, anyone can pick up my phone, enable Bluetooth from the lock screen, and it's instantly unlocked.

Is there any way to select which connectivity options can be changed while the phone is locked, or disable these options altogether?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell Smart Lock to not automatically unlock when connected to the Bluetooth device, but remain unlocked once I've unlocked the phone myself?

Comment: This will disable Bluetooth, though the setting may show on lock screen and can be tested IF you connect to office Wi-Fi from your device. [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app, set up a macro - Trigger: WiFi state change> connected to network (office) ; Action: Disable Wi-Fi; constraints -  blank. It will of course require you to manually disable office Wi-Fi when you leave office ( assuming WiFi spills over to car parking, of it doesn't, they're is no need for manual action)